# React Native - Keyboard is automatically hiding

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-top-tabs

I've got a problem with keyboard in react native. I have a component with `TextInput` inside of it. The problem is when I am touching it - keyboard is starting to show, but immediately hiding back. (Checked with event listeners of Keyboard - event `keyboardWilHide` triggers, but I don't know what triggered it).

My assumption that the core of the problem in my navigation architecture. I have `materialBottomTabNavigator` which has `materialTopTabNavigator` inside, which has `StackNavigator` inside, and my component is a screen in stack navigator. Probably some tabs properties are triggering Keyboard Hide event, but I did not found any.

(In terms of debug launched app with my component moved out of this type of navigation and everything works fine).

Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked your onChange and onFocus for TextInput if it gives some hint?

Comment: Yep, I've tried to log this case, but nothing found except that keyboard event is actually triggered. Is there any possibility to get from callback any info about what triggered KeyboardWillHide event?

Comment: I don't know if we have any way to know when KeyboardWillHide is invoked. Can you share some code snippets or any GitHub link for your screen?

Comment: @VyachAp did you get any solution for this issue?